# Is there something similar in ASP.NET to PHP's SimpleXML

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, simplexml

If I want to convert my PHP application to ASP.NET… what do you recommend and why?

I'm currently using PHP's simplexml_load_string() method because it's, well, …simple.

For example, for PHP to process an http request in the form of XML I just use:

```
$FILERAWDATA = file_get_contents("php://input");  
$xml = simplexml_load_string($FILERAWDATA);
```

Then grab the values from the xml nodes like such:

```
@$itemid = $xml->itemid;
// then use the node value as a PHP var $itemid
```

So, does ASP.NET have anything similar?

Thanks for reading.

AlejandroConsueloRodriguezMiguel -- also known as Fred  :)

Answer (score 0):

[Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Comment: thanks. I've looked at that. Have you ever used PHP's simplexml method? Do you have a small example to show?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the .Net XML namespace
and XMLDocument class:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/readwritexmltutmellli2111282005041517am/readwritexmltutmellli21.aspx

Comment: thanks. I've also seen this site. Have you ever used PHP's simplexml? Also, do you have a small example to show the use?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are lookin for ?

```
Dim xml As New XmlDocument()
xml.LoadXml(SomeXMLString)
Dim itemID as String = xml.GetElementsByTagName("itemID")(0).InnerText
```

this assumes that there is only one ItemID -> (0) first